# How to show/hide divs when slider's slides are visible/hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, show-hide

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".cont_slider .slide").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
      });

      $("#arrow-next").click(function(){
        if ($(".cont_slider .slide:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
            else {
              $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").hide();
              $(".cont_slider .slide:first").show();
            }
            return false;
      });

      $("#arrow-back").click(function(){
        if ($(".cont_slider .slide:visible").prev().length != 0)
          $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
          else {
            $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").hide();
            $(".cont_slider .slide:last").show();
          }
          return false;
      });
    });

    // show/hide squares
    if($('#slide_1').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_1').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_2').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_2').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_3').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_3').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_4').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_4').show();
    }
```

```css
#arrow-back, #arrow-next {
    background:black;
    height: 70px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 80px;
    z-index: 100000;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
  #arrow-back{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
  }
  #arrow-next{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  .cont_slider{
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    background: purple;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
  }
  #slide_1{
    background: red;
  }
  #slide_2{
    display: none;
    background: green;
  }
  #slide_3{
    display: none;
    background: orange;
  }
  #slide_4{
    display: none;
    background: blue;
  }
  .square_1{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
  }
  .square_2{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #00FFFF;
    float: left;
    display: none;
  }
  .square_3{
    position: absolute;`
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #008080;
    float: left;
    display: none;
  }
  .square_4{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #900C3F;
    float: left;
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="arrow-back">&#8249;</div>
<div id="arrow-next">&#8250;</div>
<div class="cont_slider">
  <div id="slide_1" class="slide">slide 1</div>
  <div id="slide_2" class="slide">slide 2</div>
  <div id="slide_3" class="slide">slide 3</div>
  <div id="slide_4" class="slide">slide 4</div>
</div>
<div class="square_1">

</div>
<div class="square_2">

</div>
<div class="square_3">

</div>
<div class="square_4">

</div>
```

I have a slider whose slides are visible and hidden by clicking on prev/next buttons and there are four divs square out of the slider. I would like that when, for example, the slide 3 is visible, square 3 becomes visible.

**I've tried this script but it doesn't works**

```
if($('#slide_3').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_3').show();
    }
```

**CSS**

```
  #arrow-back, #arrow-next {
    background:black;
    height: 70px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 80px;
    z-index: 100000;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
  #arrow-back{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
  }
  #arrow-next{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  .cont_slider{
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    background: purple;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
  }
  #slide_1{
    background: red;
  }
  #slide_2{
    display: none;
    background: green;
  }
  #slide_3{
    display: none;
    background: orange;
  }
  #slide_4{
    display: none;
    background: blue;
  }
  .square_1{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
  }
  .square_2{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #00FFFF;
    float: left;
    display: none;
  }
  .square_3{
    position: absolute;`
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #008080;
    float: left;
    display: none;
  }
  .square_4{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #900C3F;
    float: left;
    display: none;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="arrow-back">&#8249;</div>
<div id="arrow-next">&#8250;</div>
<div class="cont_slider">
  <div id="slide_1" class="slide">slide 1</div>
  <div id="slide_2" class="slide">slide 2</div>
  <div id="slide_3" class="slide">slide 3</div>
  <div id="slide_4" class="slide">slide 4</div>
</div>
<div class="square_1">

</div>
<div class="square_2">

</div>
<div class="square_3">

</div>
<div class="square_4">

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".cont_slider .slide").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
      });

      $("#arrow-next").click(function(){
        if ($(".cont_slider .slide:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
            else {
              $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").hide();
              $(".cont_slider .slide:first").show();
            }
            return false;
      });

      $("#arrow-back").click(function(){
        if ($(".cont_slider .slide:visible").prev().length != 0)
          $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
          else {
            $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").hide();
            $(".cont_slider .slide:last").show();
          }
          return false;
      });
    });

    // show/hide squares
    if($('#slide_1').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_1').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_2').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_2').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_3').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_3').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_4').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_4').show();
    }
```

i have changed your code

Comment: this is working man.what's the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that if I click for example the next button and the slider change from slide 1 to slide 2, when slide 2 is visible, square 2 remains hidden and square 1 remains visible (it should be hidden like slide 1).

Comment: does it works ?

Comment: @Guglielmo Albesano The reason why Slide 1-> slide 2 does not lead to square 2 remaining hidden is because the identification of square 2 was not made. Place the code for square 2 and other squares check inside a function and call it inside load and click event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the task is to repeat the check for visibility and subsequently make the decision based on the above check to show or hide the box then try outing the code inside each event handler.

```
$("#arrow-back").click(function(){
     .
     .
     . Perform the task meant for click
     // show/hide squares
    showHideFunction();
});
function showHideFunction(){
if($('#slide_1').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_1').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_2').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_2').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_3').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_3').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_4').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_4').show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check it man.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".cont_slider .slide").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
      });

      $("#arrow-next").click(function(){
        if ($(".cont_slider .slide:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
            else {
              $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").hide();
              $(".cont_slider .slide:first").show();
            }
            return false;
      });

      $("#arrow-back").click(function(){
        if ($(".cont_slider .slide:visible").prev().length != 0)
          $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
          else {
            $(".cont_slider .slide:visible").hide();
            $(".cont_slider .slide:last").show();
          }
          return false;
      });
    });

    // show/hide squares
    if($('#slide_1').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_1').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_2').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_2').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_3').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_3').show();
    }
    if($('#slide_4').is(':visible')) {
      $('.square_4').show();
    }
```

```css
#arrow-back, #arrow-next {
    background:black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 80px;
    z-index: 100000;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #arrow-back{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
  }
  #arrow-next{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  .cont_slider{
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    background: purple;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
  }
  #slide_1{
    background: red;
  }
  #slide_2{
    display: none;
    background: green;
  }
  #slide_3{
    display: none;
    background: orange;
  }
  #slide_4{
    display: none;
    background: blue;
  }
  .square_1{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    //background: yellow;
    float: left;
  }
  .square_2{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #00FFFF;
    float: left;
    display: none;
  }
  .square_3{
    position: absolute;`
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #008080;
    float: left;
    display: none;
  }
  .square_4{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #900C3F;
    float: left;
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="arrow-back">&#8249;</div>
<div id="arrow-next">&#8250;</div>
<div class="cont_slider">
  <div id="slide_1" class="slide">slide 1</div>
  <div id="slide_2" class="slide">slide 2</div>
  <div id="slide_3" class="slide">slide 3</div>
  <div id="slide_4" class="slide">slide 4</div>
</div>
<div class="square_1">

</div>
<div class="square_2">

</div>
<div class="square_3">

</div>
<div class="square_4">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you better add 'id's to your 
this would work

Comment: I think you better add 'id's to your div this would work